# How to set n-th bit of *x to v value in C

Tags: c

I need to implement this method.

I have the unsigned `* x`, I need to set `v` value in the n-th bit, using bitwise operators in C.

```
void set_bit(unsigned * x,
             unsigned n,
             unsigned v){

    //I need the code here, thanks for your help!
}
```

Comment: Did you read the C manual regarding bitwise operators? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a macro to do that

```
#define SETBIT(var, bit) ((var) |= (1 << (bit)))
```

Comment: `1U << (bit)` would be better, no UB